# TinyMCE Configuration

Tags: tinymce, django-tinymce

I have following setup for tiny MCE. As you can see in image it shows a third row of buttons . I dont know where it comes from ! There is no setting in my javascript code for a third row still it shows that there.

[image]

```
tinyMCE.init({

        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist,fullpage",

            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 :  "mybutton,|,link,unlink,|,hr,removeformat,pastetext,pasteword,cleanup,|,undo,redo,|,code",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "none",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
            convert_urls : false,
            fullpage_default_doctype: "",

        content_css : "css/content.css",
        cleanup : false,

        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add following line which fixed it.

```
theme_advanced_buttons3 : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mybutton` from the second row of buttons and the thing is gone.

I suspect you have an error in eigther the plugin-row or one of your button rows.

Comment: I removed 'myButton' but it makes no difference to third row .Whats relation between mybutton and third row ?

Comment: i tested your config in my local system and i removed "mybutton" - the 3rd row was gone

Comment: Strange cause in my case I just did put this line which fixed it . theme_advanced_buttons3 : "".